# Two pointers to the same location?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I can't seem to find the answer on here, but I'm sorry if this is a duplicate. Here's my question: When I have two pointers to the same location, then I change the address of one (let's say pointer A), will I (by accident) be changing the address of the other pointer (pointer B)? Or will pointer B's location stay the same?

Comment: Your question would be perfect with a [mcve]

Comment: "Address of pointer" is address of pointer variable itself. You cannot change it. What you are probably talking about is the *value* of the pointer, i.e. address stored *in* the pointer. If so, don't call it "address of pointer".

Comment: By "changing the address of [the pointer]", you mean just reassigning it with `=` to point to somewhere else?

Comment: You can't change a variable's address. So your question is asking about something that is impossible.

Comment: Yeah @ApproachingDarknessFish that's what I mean! Also David, I'm not talking about changing a variable's address. I'm talking about changing a pointer's value to something else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Picture speaks a thousand words.

[image: picture speaks a thousand word]

Pointers are pointing to another memory place, at the same time, they have their own memory space.

Two pointers, A and B point to the same place, yet, they are kept in separate memory locations. (Left half of the image)

If you change B, you will only change what B is pointing, A remains the same. (Right half of the image)

Answer (score 5):

Changing the contents of a pointer (as opposed to the object being pointed to) will not affect other pointers to the same object.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by `changing the object being pointed to` ? Changing its value has nothing to do with its address.

Comment: @Jarvis I made an assumption that the question was referring to the address stored by the pointer rather than the address of the pointer. I refer to the `object being pointed to` as a contrast between the contents of the pointer (an address) which can be changed without affecting other pointers, and the object stored at that address, which changes to WILL impact other pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Pointer B's location will stay the same.

Because pointer A and pointer B are different pointer,they have different memory address.That means they are independent each other although both of them point to the same memory address.

But you should be careful when you try to change pointer A's content,this operation may cause pointer B be a **wild pointer** by accident!

Answer (score 1):

You can see the output of the below code :

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int a = 3, d = 4;
    int *b = &a, *c = &a;
    std::cout << b << ", " << c << std::endl;
    b = &d;
    std::cout << b << ", " << c << std::endl;
}
```

The following is the output of the code :

```
0x7ffca3788e40, 0x7ffca3788e40
0x7ffca3788e44, 0x7ffca3788e40
```

Clearly, changing the address `b` points to, has nothing to do with the address pointed by pointer `c`.

But you can have a near-similar phenomena when you use `references`. A reference is an entity that is an alias for another object. Suppose you have

```
int &ref = a;
ref = 5;
```

Now, changing the variable `ref` will also bring a change in the value of variable `a`, equating it to 5.

Answer (score 1):

A pointer holds the memory address of a piece of data in memory.

The value of the pointer variable is this address.

```
int targetA = 1;
int targetB = 2;

int *pointerA = &targetA;
int *pointerB = &targetA;

printf("%p, %p\n", pointerA, pointerB);
// => 0x7fff5c78e8f8, 0x7fff5c78e8f8

pointerB = &targetB;

printf("%p, %p\n", pointerA, pointerB);
// => 0x7fff5c78e8f8, 0x7fff5c78e8f4
```

By assigning a different address / location to the pointer you just change what it points to, other variables are not affeted.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at this code snippet.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int * myp1, * myp2;
  int myvalue;
  myp1 = &myvalue;
  myp2 = &myvalue;
  myvalue = 10;
  cout << "first address is " << myp1 << '\n';
  cout << "second address is " << myp2 << '\n';
```

Here, the outputs are the same (when I run it, I get first address is 0x759ba27bb1d8
second address is 0x759ba27bb1d8).

```
  int myvalue2;
  myp1 = &myvalue2;
  myvalue2 = 20;
  cout << "first address is " << myp1 << '\n';
  cout << "second address is " << myp2 << '\n';
  return 0;
```

}
Here, the addresses are different, but myp2 points to the same address as above.

And it makes sense; you have two separate things pointing to the same address. Why would changing what one thing points to change the other?

A (possibly very bad analogy) would be: consider that you and someone on the other end of the world are pointing at the sky (say, at the same point in the sky). Then, you point at the ground. Just because you pointed at the ground, doesn't mean the other guy will stop pointing at the sky.

Hope that helps.